# Google Cloud create dns peering without VPC peering in different GCP projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, gcloud, google-cloud-dns, google-vpc

I' trying to learn `DNS Peering` in `Google Cloud DNS`.
I followed the google cloud guide [page](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/zones#peering-zones) but unable to create managed-zones with service account of dns peer.

Below command was executed

```
 gcloud dns managed-zones create dns-peer-zone   \
--description="peering between consumer and provider"   \
--dns-name="us-central1-a.c.provider-proj-299820.internal"   --networks=sample-vpc-consumer \
 --account=consumer-svcacct@consumer-proj-300018.iam.gserviceaccount.com  \
 --target-network=sample-vpc   --target-project=provider-proj-299820   \
--visibility=private
```

I have tried with its own DNS too as below

```
 gcloud dns managed-zones create dns-peer-zone   \
--description="peering between consumer and provider"   \
--dns-name="us-east1.c.consumer-proj-300018.internal"   --networks=sample-vpc-consumer \
 --account=consumer-svcacct@consumer-proj-300018.iam.gserviceaccount.com  \
 --target-network=sample-vpc   --target-project=provider-proj-299820   \
--visibility=private
```

Getting below error:

```
    ERROR: (gcloud.dns.managed-zones.create) 
User [consumer-svcacct@consumer-proj-300018.iam.gserviceaccount.com] does not have permission
 to access projects instance [provider-proj-299820] (or it may not exist): Forbidden
:~$
```

I had already updated DNS peer role successfully for a service account from consumer project in provider project as below

```
    gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding provider-proj-299820 \
--member="serviceAccount:consumer-svcacct@consumer-proj-300018.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
 --role=roles/dns.peer
```

Result:

```
Updated IAM policy for project [provider-proj-299820].
bindings:
- members:
```

I'm the owner of both project, provider has custom subnet in `central1` and consumer has custom subnet in `east1`. Provider network is `GLOBAL` while the consumer is `REGIONAL`
Their IP range is mutually exclusive

Comment: The only predefined role that has the required permissions is `roles/dns.admin`.https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/access-control

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley, are you talking any paritcular permission like : dns.networks.targetWithPeeringZone
 ?
Also, the role I had chosen was given in the guide document of google cloud.
I'll try to change the role to dns.admin and see if that works.

Comment: Yes, you need that permission and more on both sides of the peer. Also review @Mahboob's answer in case you have another issue.

Comment: I added the dns.admin role too , stil the error is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to activate the service account created to create the dns role in the producer project which does not have permissions to create a role in the other project
I followed the step without activating as mentioned in this [beingasre blog link](https://beingasre.blogspot.com/2020/12/google-cloud-platformgcp-dns-peering.html) and it worked

Answer (score 1):

From the error it's seems to me that the message is misleading and confusing. Based on that I found the following [PIT1](https://issuetracker.google.com/174737821) and [PIT2](https://issuetracker.google.com/148401161) as a bug on Google Issue tracker. There is no ETA at this time. However, you will get further update on the thread accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Mahboob for adding the bug details, I see in the bug the issue is about enhancing the message in case of using incorrect input parameters

Comment: I verified the service account name and the networks name , those are correct. 
I also updated the dns role to dns.admin for consumer in provider project

verified service account name listed in provider projects :

 gcloud projects get-iam-policy provider-proj-299820 |grep "consumer-svcacct@consumer-proj-300018.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

Verified the networks name as : 
gcloud compute networks list --project=provider-proj-299820 | grep "sample-vpc"
gcloud compute networks list --project=consumer-proj-300018 | grep "sample-vpc-consumer"

Comment: @Learner I have just updated my answer and include another Public Issue which also indicate that the error message is confusing and need to improve to get exact error message. I understand that your permission might be ok as Owner role also grant all the DNS permissions.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the bug. 
I added dns admin role in the consumer project too for the service account just to rule out the possibility, it still did not work . 
I'll keep an eye on this bug